# python3 -bcrypt : invalid salt

Tags: python-3.x, bcrypt

```
import bcrypt


s = "5UA@/Mw^%He]SBaU".encode('utf-8')
h = "3281e6de7fa3c6fd6d6c8098347aeb06bd35b0f74b96f173c7b2d28135e14d45"
dictionary = open("dictionary.txt","r")
for line in dictionary:
    testString =line.encode('utf-8')
    h2 = bcrypt.hashpw(testString,s)
    print(h2)
```

without the encode on s i get the error 'items need to be encoded before hashing' , however with .encode i get the error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "task3.py", line 9, in <module>
    h2 = bcrypt.hashpw(testString,s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/bcrypt/__init__.py", line 86, in hashpw
    raise ValueError("Invalid salt")
ValueError: Invalid salt
```

How do i make this salt valid for hashpw function?

Comment: I think your salt doesnt fit the bcrypt standard of bcrypt salts since there is specific requirement about length afaik, im not sure if its 128 bit. If you dont want to use own salt, you can use `bcrypt.gensalt(salt-length)` to generate a new valid salt.

Comment: @BijayRegmi oh i see , so would i need to use hashlib or something? i need the salt as is for an assignment.

Comment: for example. You can use `my_sha_hash = hashlib.sha256()` and then update your `my_sha_hash` with `my_sha_hash.update(testString.encode()+ salt.encode())` and then you can get your hash in hex form with `my_sha_hash.hexdigest()`